# Repeated background gradient misaligned by about 1 pixel

Tags: html, css

**Note:** This site is only meant to work in the latest version of Google Chrome Stable Channel.

Please see the site here : http://3.cnxical.appspot.com

**Problem**

One of the background images is a 10vmax by 10vmax responsive square, repeated to give the effect of 45 degree stripes. It is done using gradients.

The current problem to which the question refers is a ***misalignment by about 1 pixel*** that persists across resizings, which should be able to be reproduced.

[image: notice the stepping on the diagonals, and the 1 pixel corners protruding across color stops]

**Question**

How to get the result that the gradient square tiles, line up perfectly to that no "jutting corners" or "misaligned" blocks occur in the stripes? (working "hacks" are ok)

**Relevant CSS Code**

```
    body {
                background-image: 
                    -webkit-linear-gradient(
                        bottom,
                        rgba(158,158,158,0.7) 0%,
                        rgba(5,5,5,0.7) 100%
                    ),
                    -webkit-linear-gradient(
                        45deg,
                        rgba(0,255,0,0.5) 25%,
                        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 25%,
                        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%,
                        rgba(0,255,0,0.5) 50%,
                        rgba(0,255,0,0.5) 75%,
                        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 75%
                    );
                background-size: 100% 100%, 10vmax 10vmax;  
                background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;   
            }
```

**Hypothesis**

This might be due to a round-off loss of precision, or due to the combination of % values with view based values. Or due to some mistake in the code.

**What was tried so far**

- Changing the `background-size` values from view relative to pixel absolute, i.e. from `vmax` to `px`. **Effect**: Misalign persists.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see the misalignment in my latest version of Chrome. Try posting a link to the image, I'll include it for you

Comment: @ZachSaucier thank you Mr Saucier. http://picpaste.com/pics/Screen_Shot_2013-12-18_at_4.44.15_PM-ntkAlweL.1387412532.png

Comment: I do not see misalignments, after resizing my browser it kinda looks messed up, but i guess that's just a visual thing.

Comment: Okay try it again and if it's the same tell me what happened exactly.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5Rnv7/)

**CSS**

`body{background-size: 100% 100%, 10.1vmax 10vmax; }`

instead of

`body{background-size: 100% 100%, 10vmax 10vmax;}`

Also, I read about `vmax` and `vmin` and found that it's not a good idea to apply it on body tags. Reference: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css-viewport-units/

Comment: Hey, cool idea. And with respect, I still get the misalignment! Also, the article just says "text might be too small", and not "dont use it on body" so what do you say?

Comment: Yea..I guess. It's not working with your website, but that's the problem. My bad. Since it worked on fiddle, I thought it'll work on your site too. Let me check.

Comment: Ok, I get the misalignment with the fiddle. :S